# spring security rejects login csrf

Tags: java, javascript, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot with spring-security and am trying to get my login to work with javascript. Everything works fine if I use login.html and a form.  But once I use javascript I get an error about a null csrf.  I am using all json for my request and response.  I believe this means I need the _csrf token for all request POST/PUT headers except login.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
http
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();

        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .and()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .invalidSessionUrl("/");

        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

  @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService( customUserDetailsService ).passwordEncoder( encoder );
    }

}
```

Here is my javascript to submit the login request:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$("#login").click(function(){
  username=$("#username").val();
  password=$("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/login",  
   beforeSend: function(xhr){
       xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
   },
   data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
   success: function(html){
        alert("logged in");
    }
  });
return false;
});
```

And here is the error I get:

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Tue Oct 21 09:56:56 MDT 2014, status=403, error=Forbidden, message=Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'., path=/login}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@731cc24a] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

And the 403 response I receive in my browser is:

```
"Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'."
```

Is the something that I am doing wrong that all my requests POST/PUTs get rejected for this?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to excellent advice, I added the headers into all my requests and that seems to get me past the csrf issue, only to result in a 302 redirect.

I opened another question [[spring boot / spring security is ignoring /login call from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567153/spring-boot-spring-security-is-ignoring-login-call-from-javascript]) for the javascript being ignored from spring-security issue

Comment: Just add the `CSFR` token as a header. The value should be available when the page is being rendered make sure it gets added to the requests.

Comment: So I need to have the token in all put/post requests, including login?

Comment: Yes. That is to verify that the requests comes from a legitimate client.

Comment: Is there an actual value in there?

Comment: I added the js headers and no longer get the error when I go to /login.  I guess this means the request was successful since I got a 302.  However, I don't see any authentication or my breakpoints being hit, so how so I know the authentication is actually taking place?  I know that spring java configuration will provide the form for me, but since I am using javascript, do I now need to provide I login controller to handle those requests?

Comment: Not sure where your breaks points are so hard to tell what should happen. You don't need to provide anything as long as you are hitting the correct login URL.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  I have a **CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService** and I would expect the loadUserByUsername(String userName) to be called on login.  But its never called.  And since I am getting a 302 that redirects back to "/" I guess that means the login doesn't happen

Comment: And then why wouldn't it happen, that is your `defaultSuccessUrl` you have configured it as `/`. So after succesful login it redirects to `/`. It is nice that you have your own service implementation but I don't see it being injected anywhere to Spring Security, it is only autowired to be ignored.

Comment: I have the CustomUserDetailsService Autowired into my WebSecurityConfig and its annotated with @Component, but are you saying I need to do something else for it to be used to authenticated?  So its being ignored and spring security is just redirecting back to "/" because its using its own UserDetailService by default?

Comment: Yes. Currently it is only taking up memory and sitting idle... You need to inject it into the `AuthenticationManager`.

Comment: Do you mean do:  **@Bean CustomUserDetailsService authenticationManager;** in my WebSecurityConfig?

Comment: No... You need to inject/set it on the `AuthenticationManager` for which you can use the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` and set is using the `userDetailsService` method. Without setting/configuring that way it does nothing.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I have neglected to put that in my original post.  I have appended it to show how I using it.

Comment: Try making that a public method (you need to rename it) and annotate it with `@Autowired`. I'm still looking for when to use what but that might help.

Comment: No that didn't seem to do it.  I think this configuration is correct, based upon another project I created.  The only difference I can see is that this project uses javascript to do the /login and the other uses html form.