# spring boot / spring security is ignoring /login call from javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring-Boot 1.1.7, with spring security, html (no thyme-leaf) and javascript.  I am unable to get my login to work correctly when I use javascript to submit my login.  When I use html with a form, spring-security picks up the requests, authenticates and proceeds happily.  But with Javascript, I get a 302 redirect and no authentication.

Here is my configuration:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext edm = SpringApplication.run( MyApplication.class, args );
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/menu").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/libs/**").permitAll();


        http
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();

        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .and()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .invalidSessionUrl("/");

        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService( customUserDetailsService ).passwordEncoder( encoder );
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity security){
        security.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/fonts/**","/libs/**");
    }
}
```

And I have my own UserDetailsService

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findByUsername( userName );
        if ( user == null ) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException( "UserName " + userName + " not found" );
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the javascript that submits the post:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$("#login").click(function(){
  username=$("#username").val();
  password=$("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/login",  
   beforeSend: function(xhr){
       xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
   },
   data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
   success: function(html){
        alert("logged in");
    }
  });
return false;
});
```

If I make this call from the url /login, I get the spring provided login form and all works perfectly.  but I have a need to use javascript so I am wondering if there is something different I need to do to tell spring to look for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer/solution that worked for me.  Based on this article (http://patrickgrimard.com/2014/01/03/spring-security-csrf-protection-in-a-backbone-single-page-app/), adding a `CSRFTokenGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter`  and wiring it up to my security config, allowed my javascript provided parameters to be used.

```
public final class CSRFTokenGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");

        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-HEADER", token.getHeaderName());
        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-PARAM", token.getParameterName());
        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token.getToken());
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

with wiring as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterAfter(new CSRFTokenGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
..}
}
```

I am not sure why the filter is needed, but I guess spring-boot/security doesn't use that as a default.

Answer (score 1):

302 probably means your request either has invalid credentials or you are hitting filter protected area of the app. Are you sure that `/login` is the url spring filter listens to? I can't see where you set your request path for spring to listen to.. The default if I recall correctly is `/j_spring_security_check` with `j_username` and `j_password`.

Try to **override** login processing url.

Taking config from our prod as an example:

```
http
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/app/authentication")
                .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that the current spring-security now just looks for parameters "username" and "password".  But I tried using your parameter names also, and I still don't see any authentication going on.

Comment: did you try to set up loginProcessingUrl? If you can't debug it you can use rest client (like advanced rest client for chrome to see where you can actually hit)

Comment: I changed my security config to have the login processing url: **.formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")              .loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/")           .permitAll()**  and added **.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()** to make sure it wasn't being blocked.  Using Chrome I see that the post is made to /login with the credentials and csrf headers, but other than a 302, I get no other response data.